# Using CSS3 keyframes super-rainbow to change color of javascript doughnutData

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am using javascript doughnutData on my websites. I have successfully applied super-rainbow to text (an effect that changes text color). Is there anyway to target the color value within the the javascript and apply the CSS3 rainbow effect?

```
var doughnutData = [
                                {
                                    value: 70,
                                    color:"#74cfae"
                                }
```

They keyframe code I am using is as follows:

```
-webkit-animation: super-rainbow 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: super-rainbow 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: linear-super-rainbow 2s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: linear-super-rainbow 2s infinite linear;
}

    @-webkit-keyframes super-rainbow {
    0% {
        color: #333;
    }
    20% {
        color:#06C;
    }
    40% {
        color:#090;
    }
    60% {
        color:#FC0;
    }
    80% {
        color:#F00;
    }
    100% {
        color:#606;
    }
    }
@-moz-keyframes super-rainbow {
    0% {
        color: #333;
    }
    20% {
        color:#06C;
    }
    40% {
        color:#090;
    }
    60% {
        color:#FC0;
    }
    80% {
        color:#F00;
    }
    100% {
        color:#606;
    }
}
    @-o-keyframes super-rainbow {
    0% {
        color: #333;
    }
    20% {
        color:#06C;
    }
    40% {
        color:#090;
    }
    60% {
        color:#FC0;
    }
    80% {
        color:#F00;
    }
    100% {
        color:#606;
    }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes super-rainbow {
    0% {
        color: #333;
    }
    20% {
        color:#06C;
    }
    40% {
        color:#090;
    }
    60% {
        color:#FC0;
    }
    80% {
        color:#F00;
    }
    100% {
        color:#606;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `doughnutData`? Is it a library?

Comment: Yes. chart.js [see here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

Comment: You want to do a rainbow effect on Doughnut`s Texts. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you want to use (chart.js), uses `canvas` object to draw to. What this mean, in a few words: The content is not HTML based.

What would lead to: If it's not HTML, CSS do not apply to it...

chart.js uses a Canvas, and draws charts as primitives as they are (lines, squares, circles, elipses...). They do not contain `div`, `ul`, `span`... And this is a good reason: Rendering is faster and more controllable.

However, because of this, the answer for your question is `no`. That effect you made cannot be set in the properties, because it wont work.

Comment: I thought so! I wanted the effect on the actual circle. Thank you though!